# Excel IF statement, multiple answers

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm looking to write an Excel IF statement that does the following

If cell `A3` is over budget A1,
print text "Over Budget by $" and then `Sum(a3-a1)`

so, the result should look like:

> Over budget by $27

Does anyone know how I can achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/if-HP005209118.aspx

```
=IF(A3<=A1,"Within budget","Over budget by $"&(A3-A1))
```

Comment: Hoang has provided the same answer already

Comment: Thanks Rick! any idea how to also add a third layer, and have it that if the a3=a1, print text "Budget Balanced"

Comment: You need a nested function. Each if statement has the following logic =if(operation to test,if true do this, if false do this). So if you want more layers nest another function into the statement.=if(operation to test, if true do this, if false test another operation. So in your case =IF(A3>A1,"Over budget by $"&(A3-A1),IF(A3<A1, "Under budget by $"&(A1-A3), IF(A3=A1, "Balanced Budget","")))

Comment: Rick, posting virtually identical answers to earlier posts doesn't aid the community

Answer (score 3):

```
=IF(A3>A1,"Over budget by $ " &(A3-A1),"")
```

Comment: awesome, thanks.. any idea how to also add a third layer, and have it that if the a3=a1, print text "Budget Balanced"

Comment: @user1833002 `=IF(A1=A3,"Budget balanced",IF(A3<A1,"Within budget","Over budget by $ "&(A3-A1)))` (posted as a comment as Hoang deserves the accept points)

Answer (score 0):

You need a nested function. Each if statement has the following logic =if(operation to test,if true do this, if false do this). So if you want more layers nest another function into the statement.=if(operation to test, if true do this, if false test another operation. So in your case =IF(A3>A1,"Over budget by $"&(A3-A1),IF(A3<A1, "Under budget by $"&(A1-A3), IF(A3=A1, "Balanced Budget",""))) –

Comment: The question doesn't specify that handling the "under budget" case is necessary. There's also an answer marked as accepted by the OP that uses just a single IF.